# Point Graphite to Ganglia RRDs

Tags: python, linux, graphite, rrdtool, ganglia

I am following the instructions "Point Graphite to Ganglia RRDs" at https://github.com/ganglia/monitor-core/wiki/Ganglia-Graphite to analyze Ganglia RRD files.

My rrdcached was running. I see the navigation tree of metrics. If I select a metric, I only get a broken image in the composer in Graphite web UI.

```
ubuntu@graphite-server-v735i33ut4fq:~$ ps -ef | grep rrd
root      7044     1  0 18:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/rrdcached -l unix:/var/run/rrdcached.sock -j /var/lib/rrdcached/journal/ -F -b /var/lib/rrdcached/db/ -B -p /var/run/rrdcached.pid
```

If I right-click the broken image and select view image. I get back the following stack trace with the error message "Unable to connect to rrdcached: Permission denied".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite/render/views.py", line 110, in renderView
seriesList = evaluateTarget(requestContext, target)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 10, in evaluateTarget
result = evaluateTokens(requestContext, tokens)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 21, in evaluateTokens
return evaluateTokens(requestContext, tokens.expression)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite/render/evaluator.py", line 24, in evaluateTokens
return fetchData(requestContext, tokens.pathExpression)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite/render/datalib.py", line 229, in fetchData
dbResults = dbFile.fetch( timestamp(startTime), timestamp(endTime) )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite/storage.py", line 405, in fetch
rrdtool.flushcached(self.fs_path, '--daemon', settings.FLUSHRRDCACHED)
error: Unable to connect to rrdcached: Permission denied
```

What did I do wrong? Where should I look further?

By the way, I have set `FLUSHRRDCACHED = 'unix:/var/run/rrdcached.sock'` in my /etc/graphite/local_settings.py. I also have python-rrdtool installed as well.

Thanks,

David